# Suddently can't access DO Spaces locally (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, guzzle, laravel-8, laravel-storage, laravel-sail

I have a laravel site up and running. We have three copies currently working - local, staging and production.

Up until today all three of these were acccessing the same digitalocean spaces with no issue.

Today we are getting a timeout whenever a request is made from the local environment - it continues to work perfectly on staging and development. Our .env files are identical with the acception of app key / name etc. Our config file are identical. The code that makes the request is identical.

We are receiving the following error

```
Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception: Error executing &quot;ListObjects&quot; o&quot;https://example.com/?prefix=document.pdf%2F&amp;max-keys=1&amp;encoding-type=url&quot;; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 28: Failed to connect to site.com port 443: Connection timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://example.com/?prefix=document.pdf%2F&amp;max-keys=1&amp;encoding-type=url in file /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php on line 195
```

We have tried everything we can think of. We have completly restarted the local servers (laravel sail) to no effect. The only difference is the local copy of the the site is served over http whereas both staging and production are served over https. This hasn't caused an issue in the past however.

Any ideas on what could be causing this would be greatly appretiated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked with DO that there isn't some setting on their end that is rejecting your request?

Comment: Thanks for the response. We've gone through all the settings. Can't find anything. We also havent changed any settings on the DO since it was working.

Comment: If all of your keys are the same and correct, _something_ is blocking the request. It seems it isn't your network as the error suggests you are able to reach DO but that they never reply, almost like they are blocking your request from getting through. Given nothing has changed, I'd contact ther support to see what they can say.

Comment: Thanks James, it looks like you were completly correct. See my answer. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who finds in the future.

The issues resolved itself after about 12 hours.

It is almost certain that this was an issues on DO's end.

If it occurs again I'll be contacting support as @James has pointed out.